# How to perform JOINs in SurrealDB without Record links

Tags: surrealdb

The SurrealDB documentation states that the concept of JOINs is replaced through the use of Record links. But is it still possible to JOIN tables based on arbitrary columns?

Consider the following tables:

```sql
CREATE user:1 SET
    name = 'User1',
    favouriteDay = 'Monday'
;
CREATE user:2 SET
    name = 'User2',
    favouriteDay = 'Tuesday'
;

CREATE motto:1 SET 
    day = 'Monday',
    motto = 'Best day of the week'
;
CREATE motto:2 SET
    day = 'Tuesday',
    motto = 'Second best day of the week'
;
```

Is it possible to write a query to get the following result (without changing the underlying data model)?

```json
"result": [
  {
    "favouriteDay": "Monday",
    "id": "user:1",
    "name": "User1",
    "motto": "Best day of the week"
  },
  {
    "favouriteDay": "Tuesday",
    "id": "user:2",
    "name": "User2",
    "motto": "Second best day of the week"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a way to JOIN data in SurrealDB using `SPLIT`.

A query joining the two tables `user` and `motto` would look like this:

**SurrealDB**

```sql
SELECT id, name, favouriteDay, motto.motto as motto 
FROM (
    SELECT *, (SELECT * FROM motto) as motto 
    FROM user 
    SPLIT motto 
) 
WHERE favouriteDay = motto.day;
```

**SQL-equivalent**

```sql
SELECT id, name, favouriteDay, motto
FROM user JOIN motto ON user.favouriteDay = motto.day
```

---

*Explanation*:

We first query all the users and add *every* motto to each user.

```sql
SELECT *, (SELECT * FROM motto) as motto FROM user
```

We can then use `SPLIT` to *unwind* every element in the `motto` array of each `user` to a separate row.

```sql
SELECT *, (SELECT * FROM motto) as motto FROM user SPLIT motto
```

Lastly, we take the result of this query and filter all the rows where `favouriteDay` and `motto.motto` match. We also pull out the `motto` string from the `motto` object to format the output to the the desired result.

```sql
SELECT id, name, favouriteDay, motto.motto as motto FROM (
    SELECT *, (SELECT * FROM motto) as motto FROM user SPLIT motto 
) 
WHERE favouriteDay = motto.day;
```

```json
[
   {
      "favouriteDay":"Monday",
      "id":"user:1",
      "motto":"Best day of the week",
      "name":"User1"
   },
   {
      "favouriteDay":"Tuesday",
      "id":"user:2",
      "motto":"Second best day of the week",
      "name":"User2"
   }
]
```

Comment: You can simplify this a bit like this and get rid of the second `SELECT` statement: `SELECT id, name, favouriteDay, motto.motto as motto FROM (SELECT *, (SELECT * FROM motto) as motto FROM user SPLIT motto) WHERE favouriteDay == motto.day`

Comment: @GustavoBezerra - Ah, thanks for noticing. That makes it a bit less verbose ;) although I am still worried about the efficiency of the query. Seems like this may not be viable for large tables. Hopefully get implement real JOINs in the future...

Answer (score 3):

Alexander from SurrealDB here.

From a best practice perspective, it would be preferable to use [record links](https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/datamodel/records) or [graph relations](https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/statements/relate).

However, if you need to do it without either, as in this example, then this would be the cleanest approach.

```sql
SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    favouriteDay, 
    (select motto from motto where day = $parent.favouriteDay)[0].motto as motto 
FROM user;
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "favouriteDay": "Monday",
        "id": "user:1",
        "motto": "Best day of the week",
        "name": "User1"
    },
    {
        "favouriteDay": "Tuesday",
        "id": "user:2",
        "motto": "Second best day of the week",
        "name": "User2"
    }
]
```